# CloudFront Top Referrers Report - ALL referrer URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, amazon-cloudfront, referrer

In AWS I can find under:

Cloudfront >> Reports & Analytics >> Top Referrers ([CloudFront Top Referrers Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVRFc.png))

There I get the **top25 items**. How can I get **ALL** of them?

I have turned on logging in my bucket, but it seems that the referrer is not part of the log-file. Any idea how amazon collects its top25 and how I can according to that get the whole list?

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: The referer is [column 10](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#BasicDistributionFileFormat) in the logs.  The column name is `cs(Referer)` and is (iirc) shown as `-` when no referer header is present in the request.

Comment: Thanks so far, Michael - sqlbot. Will try to run the select on the sql these days. I checked several random samples from the logs and nowhere was a URL found.

My thought was also, that those top-referrers from the top25 list, come from somewhere else. Could that be?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's built in analytics are, as you've noticed, rather basic.  The data you're looking for all lives in the logfiles that you can set cloudfront up to export (in the cs(Referer) field).  If you know what you're looking for, you can set up a little pipeline to download logs, pull out the numbers you care about and generate reports.

Amazon also makes it easy[1] to set up Athena or Redshift to look directly at Cloudfront or S3 logfiles in their target bucket.  After a one-time setup, you could query them directly for the numbers you need.

There are also paid services built to fill in the holes in Amazon's default reports.  S3stat (https://www.s3stat.com/), for example, will give you a Top 200 Referrer list in its reports, with the ability to export complete lists.

[1] "easy", using Amazon's definition of the word, meaning really really hard.

Comment: 2023 and still same problem -.- I am still only able to see top 25